# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Stack Overflow when loading stored procedure in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, renderpartial

Please forgive any newbie mistakes.

I'm writing a receipt detail lookup tool in MVC 2.0 to pull up receipt details from our POS database. I have the stored procedures written that return the data that I need. I have my sprocs loaded in a repository. When I try and load these sprocs in a partial view I get a stack overflow error. If I load the same code directly in the view it works fine. Am I missing something?

Repository entry

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CSTools.Models
{
    public class QueryRepository
    {
        RDataContext DB = new RDataContext();

        public IEnumerable<CSTools.Models.spGetReceiptDataResult> GetReciptData(int  storeID, int transactionNumber)
        {
            var recipt = from rc in DB.spGetReceiptData(storeID, transactionNumber)
                         select rc;
            return recipt;
        }

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CSTools.Models;

namespace CSTools.Controllers
{
    public class RetailController : Controller
    {
        QueryRepository Queries = new QueryRepository();
        //
        // GET: /Trackside/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult ReceiptView()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult ReceiptDataView(int storeID, int transactionNumber)
        {
            var Receipt = Queries.GetReciptData(storeID, transactionNumber);
            return View(Receipt);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    ReceiptView
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>ReceiptView</h2>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("ReceiptView"); %>

</asp:Content>
```

Thanks!

Neil

Comment: Are you doing `<% Html.RenderPartial("ReceiptView"); %>` inside RecepitView? This has to end with StackOverflow and doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Ach! I am calling receiptview vs Receipdataview which is what I should be calling.... I'll get the hang of this one day.

Thanks

Neil